# More cases of visiting politicians having their own entourage/followers beat up protesters?

Tags: 20th-century

During a recent visit of Turkey's president Erdogan to Washington, [his bodyguards (and maybe other members of the entourage) attacked a small group of protestors](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/17/us/turkish-embassy-protest-dc.html). This is odd insofar as, it is a blatant and very visible violation of the host countries monopoly of force - the protestors where not directly threatening Erdogan or members of his entourage, so there was no justification of self defense.

The only other similar incident I can think of was the visit of [Persian Shah Palevi to Berlin in 1967](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schah-Besuch_1967), when so-called 'Jubelperser' attacked (aided by the police). According to [this article](http://www.qcquarterly.org/students-issue1-vol1/2016/3/4/radicalization-and-repression-in-west-germany), the 'Jubelperser' where [SAVAK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAVAK) agents, other (German language) sources claim they where recruited among Shah loyalists living in Germany and led by SAVAK personnel.

**Did, since the end of WWII, another such incident happen anywhere?**

To be clear, I am not interested in self defense by bodyguards.

Comment: I have no idea how to tag this ...

Comment: I'm not sure that all countries consider it the responsibility of their police to ensure a dignitary "doesn't have to face dissent". While they might make arrangements to side-step protesters, the police of most democratic countries would not intervene with a peaceful protest that wasn't a direct threat to the dignitary's person or party.

Comment: How will you select the authoritative answer from the list of answers provided>

Comment: Authoritative answer: One that shows one or a few incidents and demonstrates that more incidents likely didnt happen OR that shows that wit ha somewhat exhaustive search, more incidents cannot be found (hard to *prove* a negative ...) would be ok.

Comment: @SteveBird while it is very much my experience that police will shield dignitaries from protest, peaceful or not, in at least one democratic country, I will remove that from the question as this is a sideshow (I don't know who the Visitor was, but IIRC in '92 Munich's police organized a complicated choreography with large busses so the small protest rally near the path of the visitors convoy was completely shielded)

Comment: fIIRC when Qaddaffi visited the UN, he was not only accompanied by his own entourage, but armed. I think POTUS has a secret service detail in every country he visits, and I expect that most foreign leaders are accorded equivalent privileges.

Comment: Would the 1984 shooting of anti-Gaddafi protesters, and the [murder of WPC Yvonne Fletcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_of_Yvonne_Fletcher) outside the Libyan embassy in London count?  Automatic weapons were fired into the crown from inside the embassy, but Gaddafi himself wasn't in London at the time.

Comment: No, I'm looking for incidents connected to visits - but thanks for the reminder I had forgotten about that episode.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace People seem to follow two behavioural patterns (according to my own subjective observations): 1 The earliest posted answer is preferred over later ones. 2. Having accepted or upvoted an answer , there is an unwillingness or disinterest to undo one's vote and switch to another answer, even if this appears as the better one.

Comment: Does a second incident involving Erdogan's bodyguards count? I think they have done that at least one other time before that Washington visit.

Answer (score 1):

[Murder of London Police Officer Yvonne Fletcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_of_Yvonne_Fletcher) at St. James Square London.

April 17, 1984.  At demonstration outside of the Libyan Embassy in London with about 75 protesters demonstrating against the government of Colonel Muammar Gaddafi. Specifically protesting against Gaddafi's recent execution of two students in Libya.

The London police had met the protesters at the embassy and had put up barriers to keep the protesters away from counter protesters.  About 10:15 am,  machine gun fire erupted from inside the embassy targeting the anti Gaddafi protesters, wounding 11 people including an unarmed London police officer on duty there to help manage the protesters.  The officer was mortally wounded in the attack.  [Yvonne Fletcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvCHd.jpg) who died at the scene.

I remember at the time it was reported that a nephew of Gaddafi was in the embassy and was claimed to be the shooter.  In 2015 the British picked up [Dr Saleh Ibrahim Mabrouk](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2015/nov/22/libyan-man-arrested-over-1984-death-of-yvonne-fletcher), a former Libyan Education Minister and advisor to Gaddafi and charged him with the crime.  The case was eventually dismissed when the British government reportedly [declined to allow sensitive intelligence in the prosecution](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/05/16/suspect-yvonne-fletcher-murder-goes-free-home-office-blocks/).

[image: Yvonne Fletcher]

The Libyan government in 1999 accepted responsibility for the death of Yvonne Fletcher, and paid compensation to her family.

> The British government took no further official action following the ending of diplomatic relations with Libya. Some unconfirmed reports even suggested that Fletcher's murderer had been hanged shortly after returning to Libya in 1984. But at a meeting with the British ambassador to Egypt in 1992, Libyan Colonel Abdul Fatah Younis apologised on behalf of the Libyan government and offered to extradite her killers. However, the Foreign Office did not accede to the offer.

Answer (score -1):

A [Turkish minister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Dutch%E2%80%93Turkish_diplomatic_incident) went to Holland for a (Turkish) political rally in March 2017. She was told not to do that, but she traveled by car to the Turkish consulate in Rotterdam. There she and her entourage were stopped by Dutch anti terrorist police and escorted out of the country. The news reported/insinuated she was declared persona non grata, but I can't find that in (official) writing.

The incident was very welcome for both Erdogan and premier Rutte of The Netherlands as that time. Edgogan needed someone bad to focus his attention on, as did Rutte. Consequently, he won the elections, following a week later.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @justCal There was some violence involved here.

Comment: Perhaps you should include some quotes showing the similarity, where the protesters were assaulted by bodyguards, as in the query.